# Multiple Processes in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I need to start several (like two dozen per machine, with at least eight servers) nearly indentical processes under Linux, each with their own command line arguments and each in their own directory. I don't want to do this by hand.

What is the best way to do this? Is it with /etc/init.d the way that httpd does it (you see several processes running under that), or is there some other way?

I should add, that I would also like them to start automatically if they die, and/or at a certain time, so probably at least cron and maybe monit has to be part of the solution?

Comment: I should add, that I would also like them to start automatically if they die, and/or at a certain time, so probably at least cron and maybe monit has to be part of the solution?

Comment: If you're adding to your question, click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11004050/edit) link under your question and edit the question.  Comments shouldn't contain vital information without which your question can't be answered.

Comment: Do these processes need to be associated with a controlling terminal, or can they be run in the background?

Comment: Can you not do this with a shell script?

Comment: It really depends on what these processes are. You'll have to provide more context (using "Edit", like @ghoti says).

Comment: why is this being marked as off topic?

Comment: @PreetSangha: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This question relates more to system configuration than to programming.

Comment: @Johnsyweb - I agree but scripting is programming too. I know it's grey area though.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the processes to be associated with a controlling terminal, you could consider using [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).  With Screen, you could create a configuration file like:

```
startup_message off
screen -t foo 1 /path/to/someprogram
screen -t bar 2 /path/to/another
```

If you are okay just backgrounding them, then ... just background them.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/nohup /path/to/someprogram &
/usr/bin/nohup /path/to/another &

echo "All done!"
```

If you need them to restart when they die, then consider wrapping them in a relauncher.  Look at [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), for instance.  Or a simple shell script like:

```
while ! /path/to/flakeybinary; do
  echo "Darn, died again." >&2
done
echo "Exited normally, yay."
```

Comment: Thanks. So for the parameters, can I say /usr/bin/nohup /path/to/someprogram param1 param2 &

Comment: I think that would be a worthwhile experiment for you.